# Joomla 2.5 back end pagination is not working properly

Tags: joomla-2.5, pagination

Joomla 2.5 back end  Pagination is getting but not working properly

- I tried to work on Pagination of Joomla 2.5 Backend (I mean in Component Creation).
- I placed pagination related data in form, It's Showing Pagination but when I am         clicking on any number it's redirecting to another page.

When I click on 'new' button it's showing previous selected data(I mean count of Pagination like 10,20,... All)
Please give me suggestions

Form Code

---

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_newsletters'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="newsletters-form">
        <table class="adminlist">
                <thead><?php echo $this->loadTemplate('head');?></thead>
                <tfoot><?php echo $this->loadTemplate('foot');?></tfoot>
                <tbody><?php echo $this->loadTemplate('body');?></tbody>
        </table>
         <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="from" value="artist" />
                <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
</form>
```

dafulthead.php

---

```
        <th width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="" onclick="checkAll(<?php echo count($this->items); ?>);" />
        </th> 
         <th>
                Artist Id
        </th>
        <th>
                Artist Name
        </th>
</tr>
```

defaultbody.php

---

```
 <?php foreach($this->items as $i => $item): ?>
                <tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?>">

                <td>
                        <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <?php echo $item->id; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://<?php echo $host.'/'.$item->username;?>" target='_blank'><?php echo $item->username; ?></a>
                </td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

defaultfoot

---

```
<tr>
      <td colspan="3"><?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please, post form code here

Comment: Please post your model. You need to set the pagination filters in your model::getListQuery method. Also you need to specify filter_fields in your config in the model::_construct before calling parent::__construct

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to insert the below code:**

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getLimitBox(); ?>
```

**Get the pagination values in view.html.php**

```
function display( $tpl = null )
    {
    $this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination');
    }
```